# add value of attribute with specific condition on list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code.

```
<ul>
<li><span id='' key="num">30</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="0">40</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

how do i add (id="disable") to only that span of  list item which have attribute (key="0")

i am using this code .

```
$(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('span').attr('key') == '0' ) $(this).attr('span:id','disable')
  });
})
```

Comment: `$(this).find('span').attr('id','disable')`

Comment: You can be more specific with your selector `$('li span')` which will make the source code slightly less. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/r6hqkf92/)

Comment: right..it works for me...

Answer (score 1):

Using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
$('li span[key="0"]').attr('id', 'disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).find('span').attr('id','disable')`

```js
$(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('span').attr('key') == '0' ) $(this).find('span').attr('id','disable')
  });
})
```

```css
#disable{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span id='' key="num">30</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="0">40</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

But instead of using `.each` to loop you can just use `$('li > span[key=0]').attr('id','disable');`

```js
$(function(){
  $('li > span[key=0]').attr('id','disable');
})
```

```css
#disable{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><span id='' key="num">30</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="0">40</span></li>
<li><span id='' key="num">20</span></li>
</ul>
```

> **Note:** Don't duplicate Id .. if you intend to use the code for more than one element use class instead